# Post a facebook page/feed with image using graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm struggling to post a facebook page/feed with a image.
I'm following all the documentation but, damm :(, it's not working

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.10/page/feed#publish

using the `object_attachment` to pass and upload photo id.

I've tried with an already uploaded image and a new upload but
Nothing appears to work

If i run this, all works as expected but the image does not work

```
$args = array( 'access_token'  => $pag_access_token,
               'message' => $description,
               'object_attachment' => $photoID,
               'link' => $link);
$status = $facebook->api("/$facebookUsername/feed", 'post', $args);
```

Note: `$photoID` is a valid facebook photo.

Result:
[image: Page feed after run the above code]

Any thoughts??

### Update: SOLUTION

Thanks to @Norbert insights heres how we can accomplish that:

Using the Graph api we need to pass the `access_token`, `the link` (important) and a `description` (optional)

1. On the api endpoint, i was just sharing the message and the link to my frontend page.

   $args = array( 'access_token'  => $pag_access_token,
                  'message' => "option text",
                  'link' => $options['link']);

   ```
   $status = $facebook->api("/$facebookpage/feed", 'post', $args);
   ```

With the above code you will be able to share to facebook feed your message, but without the title of your post and the image.

To do that you will need to add the following **metadata** into your destination page ($link that was shared)

2.

```
<meta property="og:url" content="YOUR URL">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:title" content="URL TITLE">
<meta property="og:description" content="SMALL DESCRIPTION">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://IMAGE SERVED WITH HTTP">
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://IMAGE SERVED AS HTTPD">
```

if the url you want to share is served over https you must also include the `og:image:secure_url`
They need to be served under the same protocol.

Hope this help everyone with the same problem.

Regards

Comment: Remove either the link or the object_attachment field. If I remember correctly the combination of both does not work.

Comment: yeah it worked!!:) do you know how i can also had a link to a external page.?
My intention is to link that article to my website to read the full info! Thanks

Comment: I think the idea here is to add the correct open graph tags on your side and only add the link. The image is taken from the open graph tags.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#markup

Comment: I need to use use open graph to add that feed to facebook whenever i click a save button via backoffice. Any thoughts?

Comment: You were right, it had to be a combination of graph with markup..
I've only shared the link, and it working like a charm.
Thank you so much

Comment: Hi Bruno, I'm trying to do the same thing. On front-end I've a post button which will call my back-end API which collects post information like message, link, picture url etc from database and uses /v2.10/{page-id}/feed endpoint to post it on the page but it just shows link and message no image. Can you please explain how did you achieved that?

Comment: Please can someone help on how to send a message to the feed with a picture from the local hdd and not a url. Seems impossible to find this.

Comment: thanks for updating your post with the solution, but you should add it as an answer and then mark it as the solution instead